# Evaluating custom directive values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to write a custom directive that simply triggers a specified event when an expression evaluates to true. The following will work with a single value being bound-

```
<div ng-trigger="value.someBoolean" /> 

app.directive('ngTrigger', [
    "$timeout","$log", function($timeout,$log) {
        return {
            restrict:"A",
            link: function(scope, elem, attr) {

                scope.$watch(attr.ngTrigger, function (e) {

                    if (e) {
                        $timeout(function() {
                            elem.triggerHandler('someevent');
                        });
                    } else {
                        $timeout(function () {
                            elem.triggerHandler('someotherevent');
                        });
                    }


                });

            }
        };

    }
]);
```

However this method will fail if you try and bind a more complex expression like -

```
<div ng-trigger="!value.someBoolean && value.someOtherBoolean" />
```

How can I move this directive from using a simple watcher to evaluating this expression? And, how can I be sure to know when both of the expression members change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I figured it out. Using the $parse service. [This](http://ng.malsup.com/#!/$parse-and-$eval) blog post helped a lot.

I changed my directive to the following -

```
  app.directive('ngTrigger', [
    "$timeout","$parse","$log", function($timeout,$parse,$log) {
        return {
            restrict:"A",
            link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
                //create a model from the expression using parse
                var model = $parse(attr.ngTrigger);
                //watch the resulting model
                scope.$watch(model, function(val) {
                    if (val) {
                        $timeout(function () {
                            elem.triggerHandler(attr.ngTriggerTrue);
                        });
                    } else {
                        $timeout(function () {
                            elem.triggerHandler(attr.ngTriggerFalse);
                        });
                    }

                });

            }
        };

    }
]);
```

This method works great with

```
<div ng-trigger="someValue.someBoolean"></div>
```

and

```
<div ng-trigger="someValue.someBoolean && someValue.someOtherBoolean"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try providing a watch with function instead of string expression and use scope.$eval:

`scope.$watch(function(scope){return scope.$eval(attr.ngTrigger)}, function (e) {`

This is similar to the parse approach you have highlighted.